# Why sfml does not play the file inside a function in this python code?

Tags: python, file, audio, python-3.x, sfml

```
from tkinter import *

import sfml


window = Tk()

window.minsize( 640, 480 )


def sonido():
    file = sfml.Music.from_file('poco.ogg')
    file.play()


test = Button ( window, text = 'Sound test', command=sonido )
test.place ( x = 10, y = 60)

window.mainloop()
```

Using Windows 7, Python 3.3, sfml 1.3.0 library, the file it is played if i put it out of the function. ¿ what am i doing wrong ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

google comp.lang.python group: It seems that garbage collector release 'file', cause is a local variable inside 'sonido' function. So using global variable 'file' fixed the problem.

As i want to learn a good programming methodology the best way to do that will be make 'file' a member of a class wich will contain the root window object. So. i will no use globals.

Thanks for reading.